# How to get a user's hostmask with Twisted IRCClient

Tags: python, twisted, irc, twisted.internet, twisted.words

I'm trying to get the hostmask for a user, to allow some authentication in my IRCClient bot. However, it seems to be removed from all responses? I've tried 'whois', but it only gives me the username and the channels the user is in, not the hostmask.

Any hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, when I override RPL_WHOISUSER, I can get the information after issuing an IRCClient.whois.

(And yes, did search for it before I posted my question, but had an epiphany right after I posted my question...)